# Spring : Caught EmptyResultDataAccessException causing entire transaction to rollback

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

I have two methods are shown below.

```
@Transactional
public void methodA(){
    logger.trace("Executing methodA");
    methodB()
    logger.trace("Executing methodA completed");
}

public void methodB(){
    //other codes here
    try{
        staffDao.queryById(1)   //Fetch a record from database
    }catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException e){
        logger.trace("Staff does not exists")
    }
    //other codes here
}
```

When there occurs an `EmptyResultDataAccessException` within `methodB()`
, the entire transaction started on `methodA()` is rollbacked, by below exception

> org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException:
>   Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

I know this is the default behaviour of spring `@Transactional` annotation.

For my case, I need to commit the transaction even when there is an `EmptyResultDataAccessException`. As `EmptyResultDataAccessException` is a `RuntimeException`, I can't use the `noRollBackFor` attribute of `@Transactional` annotation.

Can anyone suggest a solution ?

Comment: A quick solution can be to make EmptyResultDataAccessException a checked exception, as spring doesn't roll back in case of checked exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I have not looked closely at your code yet but if you just need a way to not rollback the transaction for a particular exception, you can mark that in `@Transactional` annotation.

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = {EmptyResultDataAccessException.class})
public void methodA(){
.
.
}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#noRollbackFor--

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code of deleteById in SimpleJpaRepository

```
public void deleteById(ID id) {
    Assert.notNull(id, "The given id must not be null!");
    this.delete(this.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> {
        return new EmptyResultDataAccessException(String.format("No %s entity with id %s exists!", this.entityInformation.getJavaType(), id), 1);
    }));
}
```

I thought this is just a convenience method. If I don't want the exception I just implement it the way I need it:

```
repo.findById(id).ifPresent(repo::delete);
```